# Meu custom Dialog só aparece após o for executar todo

Tags: android, dialog

Estou tendo um problema para consumir um custom Dialog numa Activity do Android.

Eu seleciono o texto que aparece no Dialog de acordo com a resposta anterior e o acúmulo de respostas "sim" ou "não" do usuário, o problema é que tentei colocar um "for" para poder ficar exibindo essas perguntas até obter o resultado final e ele na verdade gera X dialogs com a mesma pergunta ao invés de esperar a resposta para gerar a próxima.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
    public void realizaPerguntas() {

    for (int i = 0; i < totalSintomas(); i++) {

        if (primeira == "") {
            primeira = "1";
            pergunta(v, pegaPrimeiraPergunta(v));
        } else {
            pergunta(v, pegaOutrasPerguntas(v));
            if (checaResultado().equalsIgnoreCase("FIM")) {
                Toast.makeText(contextoApp,
                        "Você pode ter: " + possiveldoenca,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

---

```
    public String pegaPrimeiraPergunta(View v) {

    b = new Banco(contextoApp, "Doencas.db", null, 1);
    int maisocorrencias = 0;
    String sintoma = "";

    Cursor c = b
            .getConnection()
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT CODSIN, COUNT(CODSIN) AS SINTOMAS FROM SINTOMA_DOENCA GROUP BY CODSIN ORDER BY SINTOMAS DESC",
                    null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            if (c.getInt(1) >= maisocorrencias) {
                maisocorrencias = c.getInt(1);
                sintoma = c.getString(0);
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return sintoma;

}
```

---

```
    public String pegaOutrasPerguntas(View v) {

    b = new Banco(contextoApp, "Doencas.db", null, 1);
    int maisocorrencias = 0;
    String sintoma = "";

    String param = dnotin;
    String param2 = in;

    if (param.length() == 0) {
        if (param2.length() == 0) {
            param = "";
            param2 = "";

        } else {
            param = dnotin.substring(0, dnotin.length() - 1);
            param2 = in.substring(0, in.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    Cursor c = b
            .getConnection()
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT CODSIN, COUNT(CODSIN) AS SINTOMAS FROM SINTOMA_DOENCA WHERE CODDOE NOT IN (?) AND CODSIN NOT IN (?) GROUP BY CODSIN ORDER BY SINTOMAS DESC",
                    new String[] { param, param2 });
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            if (c.getInt(1) >= maisocorrencias) {
                maisocorrencias = c.getInt(1);
                sintoma = c.getString(0);
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return sintoma;

}
```

---

```
    public String checaResultado() {

    b = new Banco(contextoApp, "Doencas.db", null, 1);

    int qtd = conta_ocorrencias(',', in);

    if (in.length() == 0) {

        b.close();
        return "";

    } else {
        Cursor c = b
                .getConnection()
                .rawQuery(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT CODDOE FROM SINTOMA_DOENCA WHERE CODSIN IN (?)",
                        new String[] { in.substring(0, in.length() - 1) });

        if (c.getCount() == qtd) {

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    possiveldoenca = c.getString(0);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            b.close();

            return "FIM";
        } else {
            b.close();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    public void pergunta(View v, final String sintoma) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pergunta);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    Button sim = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btsim);
    Button nao = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnao);
    tvpergunta = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvpergunta);

    String perg = "";
    b = new Banco(contextoApp, "Doencas.db", null, 1);

    Cursor c = b.getConnection().query("SINTOMA",
            new String[] { "CODSIN", "DESSIN" }, "CODSIN = ?",
            new String[] { sintoma }, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            perg = c.getString(1);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    tvpergunta.setText("Você tem " + perg + "?");

    sim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            in += sintoma + ",";
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    nao.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            snotin += sintoma + ",";
            notInDoencas();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Você fala num Dialog mas não vejo chamada alguma ao Dialog no seu código.

Comment: Opa, falha minha, faltou a função "pergunta" que gera os dialogs. Vou editar

Answer (score 0):

Os Dialogs são executados de forma assíncrona: o método `show()` retornada imediatamente após ser chamado, prosseguindo a execução do programa na linha seguinte.
É por isso que durante a execução do `for` são abertos vários Dialogs.

Não me é possível/fácil analisar o seu código ao pormenor no entanto sugiro duas opções:

1 - Substituir o Dialog por uma Activity/Fragment.
2 - Gerir a necessidade de novas perguntas dentro do  método `sim.setOnClickListener()` do Dialog.